# Cannot force rc-tooltip opacity to 1

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, tooltip

We have built our tooltips on top of rc-tooltip, but even with our custom CSS, the tooltip does not appear to have an opacity of 1. It is still translucent. See in the picture (you can see the text in the background):
[image: bad opacity]

I've tried forcing the opacity value like so:

```
.silo-tooltip .rc-tooltip {
  /* Material-UI's modal is 1300 */
  z-index: 1400;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

But this is not having an effect. Is this a known issue, or am I missing a critical piece of info here?

Comment: What do you see when you use your browser's dev tools inspect facility? Can you put that code into your question (the relevant HTML and CSS). Are you sure that text is not on an image?

Comment: Same, I hope you have found a way around it, but if not then check this: https://github.com/react-component/tooltip/issues/215

I found it while also googling for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is taken from here and all credits belong the OP: https://github.com/ReactTooltip/react-tooltip/issues/277#issuecomment-414763398

Add the following class:

```css
.opaque {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Then in your JSX:

```
<ReactTooltip className={'opaque'}>
```

This worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

adding an extra style removes the transition property.

you can alter the --rt-opacity variable, it is initially set to 0.9
`--rt-opacity: 1 !important;`